# How can I make the text from the widget wrap?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have the following code:

```
GridTile(
      footer: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(4))),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          child: GridTileBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
            title: Flexible(
                child: Text(
              exam.examSpecifications.subject,
              overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
            )),
            subtitle: Text(exam.examSpecifications.examName),
          )),
      child: exam.examImage,
    );
  }
```

What I get is the following behaviour:

[image]

Ideally, I would like this to show as

```
   Some Other
   Subject
   Some Other ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you want your text to have an enter after the end of word?

Comment: Exactly, I want it to break so to speak and continue on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to I understand what you want. You can set overflow and softWrap property of title Text like code below and remove Flexible widget:

```
title: Text(
                  exam.examSpecifications.subject,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
```

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for. I didn't know about the softWrap property. Thank you!